# use of keystore alias in android and how to use in real life project development?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android developer. I read some tutorial available on internet.
How to create sign apk. I this tutorial one keyword comes **'keyalias'**. I don't under stand the purpose of keyalias.

***What is the use of key-alias?***

Please help to under stand this concept.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry i don't understand  "A keystore entry is identified by an alias, and it consists of keys and certificates that form a trust chain" this line and how to use keyalias in project development.

Comment: A keystore can hold multiple keys. Each key in the keystore has a name, called the key alias. To specify a key to use for some operation (e.g., signing a JAR/APK), you supply the key alias. In the world of computers, we have many types of files that hold individually-named elements, such as databases (rows identified by a primary key). This is no different.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), an alias "is a name that you will use later when signing your app." This is related to your key, which lets you run and debug your app without typing the password every time you make a change to your project.

Comment: I read developer doc but i don't under stand storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"           ---- keyAlias what is the purpose.